# Why is requiring more attacks to trigger a combo, a good thing?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

Soul of Thamasa, seems to make it so that you need to do one more attack before you trigger combo. Which seems like a bad thing. But considering it requires 6e to open it's sphere, and it reduces HP to 66%, that must be a good thing, somehow.

Also, guides talk about switching profiles to avoid triggering a combo.

Don't you want to trigger combos as much as possible? So why would we want a item to require one more hit before a combo is triggered? Then you just get less extra powerful strikes, right?

Answer (score -1):

simple answer is for faster physical attack staggering method.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: in the end of combo, Lightning always jump back from enemy thus more time needed for staggering enemy.
Another reason to make "Perfect Timing" easier.